# Problema com bot no Discord: ativo, porém não responde aos comandos

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Não estou identificando nenhum problema no meu código, porém, minha falta de experiência pode estar me impedindo de detectar possíveis erros. O bot está ativo e aparece como online no Discord, porém não está respondendo aos comandos pré-definidos com o prefixo "." e outras solicitações semelhantes. Apesar de ter feito várias modificações, ainda não encontrei uma solução para o problema. Gostaria de pedir ajuda para identificar a causa raiz do problema e aprender a corrigi-lo. Agradeço antecipadamente por qualquer orientação que possam me oferecer.

---

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [8] });
const prefix = '.';
const math = require('mathjs');


client.login('RemoviMeuToken');

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    if (command === 'ping') {
      message.channel.send('Pong!');
    } else if (command === 'calc') {
      // ...
    } else if (command === 'guess') {
      // ...
    } else if (command === 'hangman') {
      // ...
    } else if (command === 'piadas') {
      // ...
    } else if (command === 'help') {
      // ...
    }
  else if (command === 'calc') {
    try {
      const result = math.evaluate(args.join(' '));
      message.channel.send(`${args.join(' ')} = ${result}`);
    } catch (error) {
      message.channel.send('Entrada inválida');
    }
  } else if (command === 'guess') {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let attempts = 5;
    message.channel.send(`Estou pensando em um número entre 1 e 100. Você tem ${attempts} tentativas para adivinhar.`);

    const filter = m => {
      return m.author.id === message.author.id && !isNaN(m.content);
    };
  
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: attempts, time: 30000 });

    collector.on('collect', m => {
      const guess = parseInt(m.content);
      if (guess === number) {
        collector.stop();
        message.channel.send(`Parabéns, você adivinhou o número ${number}!`);
      } else if (guess < number) {
        message.channel.send(`O número é maior do que ${guess}.`);
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`O número é menor do que ${guess}.`);
      }
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
        if (collected.size === attempts) {
          message.channel.send(`Desculpe, você esgotou suas tentativas. O número era ${number}.`);
        }
      });
      } if (command === 'hangman') {
    const words = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry', 'fig', 'grape'];
    const word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    let lives = 7;
    let hiddenWord = word.split('').map(() => '_');
    message.channel.send(`A palavra é ${hiddenWord.join(' ')}. Você tem ${lives} vidas.`);
  
    const filter = m => {
      return m.author.id === message.author.id && m.content.length === 1 && /^[a-z]$/i.test(m.content);
    };
  
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 60000 });
  
    collector.on('collect', m => {
      const letter = m.content.toLowerCase();
      if (word.includes(letter)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (word.includes(letter)) {
            hiddenWord[i] = letter;
          }
        }
        message.channel.send(`A palavra é ${hiddenWord.join(' ')}.`);
        if (!hiddenWord.includes('_')) {
          collector.stop();
          message.channel.send('Parabéns, você acertou a palavra!');
        }

        
    } else {
        lives--;
        if (lives === 0) {
          message.channel.send(`Game over! A palavra era ${word}.`);
          collector.stop();
        } else {
          message.channel.send(`A letra ${letter} não existe na palavra. Você tem ${lives} vidas restantes.`);
        }
      }
      
    });
  } else if (command === 'piadas') {
      const piadas = [
        'Por que a galinha atravessou a rua? Para chegar ao outro lado!',
      ];
  
      const piada = piadas[Math.floor(Math.random() * piadas.length)];
      message.channel.send(piada);
  } else if (message.content === `${prefix}help`) {
      message.channel.send('Aqui estão todos os meus comandos disponíveis:');
      message.channel.send('.ping - Teste minha latência\n.calc [expressão] - Calcule expressões matemáticas\n.guess - Jogue um jogo de adivinhação\n.hangman - Jogue o jogo da forca\n.piadas - Veja algumas piadas\n.help - Veja todos os meus comandos disponíveis');
    }
});
```